# Unable to use bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-dropdown.js at the same time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using modal and dropbox js of twitter bootstrap in my project and having problem using the two.
I have added the following script tags in my html -
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>`
Now, if I keep both tags, dropdown js does not work but if I remove the first one, dropdown works but I cannot use modal. Is adding a separate js for modal dialog i.e `bootstrap-modal.js` is the only solution or am I missing something here?

Comment: Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file. you do not need the dropdown.js if you include bootstrap.min.js

Comment: You can also make a custom bootstrap[.min].js file, with only the necessary plugins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file. you do not need the bootstrap-dropdown.js if you include bootstrap.min.js

From the bootstrap page
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware about it.

Answer (score 0):

Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file. you do not need the bootstrap-dropdown.js if you include bootstrap.min.js.
I also face the same problem sometimes. Sometime its difficult to predict the behavior of scripts with twitter bootstrap. Like there is plugin for dropdown in bootstrap.js but still not working. if you include separate dropdown.js then there is no issue