# Drop down menu doesn't work, everything else does

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am making my first steps in bootstrap. I basically recreated one of the templates on my own. It works fine, with the exception that the drop down menu (in the navigation bar) doesn't work.

I am puzzled because:

1) The transition to mobile mode works fine. It's nav menu also works fine.

2) I have included every single file I have gotten in the download and I think it acts as if a file hasn't been included.

3) Since I thought I am making something wrong  I copied this part of the HTML directly from the website and it still doesn't work.

This is the *entire* source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">     
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>     

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>

     <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top asd">
      <div class="navbar-inner asd">
        <div class="container asd">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav asd">
              <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>  

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include bootstrap-dropdown.js in your file: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns

Add this to your scripts at the bottom (after you include jquery):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

**Edit: Important**

> The problem is that you are including both bootstrap.js and
>   bootstrap.min.js. Similar problem was encountered here (which is where
>   I found it originally):
>   [Unable to use bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-dropdown.js at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727315/unable-to-use-bootstrap-min-js-and-bootstrap-dropdown-js-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Hm... In my download I only have 2 files: bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js. From what I've read they should contain the functions of all modules. Is the drop down module independent ?

Comment: It shouldn't be, try removing either bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js. I believe that is the problem, didn't see that before. So just have bootstrap.min.js included and delete the script tag above it.

Comment: Thank you, sir, that fixed my problem. If you have a spare minute, do you mind telling me why when including both files the system breaks?

Comment: I believe that it is running the script twice on the dropdown (once for bootstrap.js and once for bootstrap.min.js), which would toggle it on after the bootsrtap.js function runs, and then immediately toggle it off when the min.js file runs. Also, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891278/what-is-the-danger-in-including-the-same-javascript-library-twice

Answer (score 1):

After deleting duplicated `link` and `script` lines (you don't have to import both normal and minimized file, like `js/bootstrap.js` and `js/bootstrap.min.js`), [I've tested your file](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDXuHI) and I cannot find errors.

So I suggest you to check all of your paths because something is missing (probably `bootstrap.js`): use Chrome Console or FireBug to see what resources are not loading in your environment, and try to convert relative path to absolute ones (like `/js/bootstrap.min.js`) whenever is possible to avoid common file import pitfalls.

P.S: I assume that you've got the complete last stable version of Bootstrap and not a customized one.